# How to check if a job is running in Quartz Framework

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to use [Quartz Framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) in my application. There are two jobs in the scheduler. Now I want to check if job1 is running. How can I check? I have tried to Google it but failed to find the solution.

I am following the first of example from Quartz distribution.

Comment: I've answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31479434/2819501

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()) to get a list of all jobs which are currently running.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that `scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()` just checks for the current scheduler instance，not the whole cluster.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to check across the whole cluster?