# Quartz scheduler check for currently executing jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have no `JobExecutionContext`. What happens if I use `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs` but do not filter for `getFireTime` ? Like in the method below.

I'm looking at [How to check whether Quartz cron job is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282441/how-to-check-whether-quartz-cron-job-is-running) for inspiration.

```java
    /**
     * 
     * @param jk JobKey
     * @return
     * @throws SchedulerException
     */
    public boolean isJobRunning(JobKey jk)
            throws SchedulerException {
        List<JobExecutionContext> currentJobs = this.getJobScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

        for (JobExecutionContext jobCtx : currentJobs) {
            String thisJobName = jobCtx.getJobDetail().getKey().getName();
            String thisGroupName = jobCtx.getJobDetail().getKey().getGroup();
            if (jk.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(thisJobName) && jk.getGroup().equalsIgnoreCase(thisGroupName)
                    //&& !jobCtx.getFireTime().equals(this.getJobScheduler().getContext().getFireTime())
                ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
```