# Quartz Scheduler job queue

Tags: java, scheduler, quartz

would there be a entry for a currently executing cron job in Quartz scheduler Job queue ,or will the Job queue only have the entries for the future scheduled jobs

Comment: does that mean job queue will have an identifier for the currently executing job ,if i clear the job queue will it clear only the future scheduled jobs or will it clear the currently executing and future scheduled jobs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether Quartz cron job is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282441/how-to-check-whether-quartz-cron-job-is-running)